# How to find if a game code has multiple users using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 23 users and their game attributes per game. I have merged all 23 csvs together and added another column called UserID (1-23). Each user uses a game code to play the game and a user might use the same game code multiple times. I want to check if any of the users have the same game code. So essentially, is a game code used by multiple users?

[My table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cp1s.png)

`df["Game Code"].value_counts()`

gives me every game code with the count - but I want to know how many users per game code(there's 413 game codes)

And then after I'd want to drop the rows with game codes with different users.

Any help is appreciated! Let me know if you'd want more information.

Comment: df.groupby('Game Code')['UserID'].nunique()

Comment: that worked thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple options for you.

I made a little demo data set based on your description.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"UserId": [1,2,3,4,1], "GameCode": ["a", "b", "c","a", "d"]})
```

This first option will get you a Series that maps your game code to the list of users that have used that game code. Any game code with a list greater than 1 was probably shared between the users who's IDs are in the list.

```py
df.groupby("GameCode")["UserId"].unique()
```

This produces

```
GameCode
a    [1, 4]
b       [2]
c       [3]
d       [1]
Name: UserId, dtype: object
```

If you just want to know if this is happening but you don't care about who the users are then you can do the below.

```py
df.groupby("GameCode").size()
```

```
GameCode
a    2
b    1
c    1
dtype: int64
```

The second one may be slightly faster.

I hope that helps!